# DIU does not increase not more than 4 on copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from GCP(Big Query) Azure Storage Gen2 parquet file with below configuration. Increased DIU from 4 to 16 but during runtime the DIU does not go beyond 4. Can you please help on how to increase the DIU to make my process faster?

1. using preserve hierarchy
2. Data size 12 millions with 3gb
3. Throughput is 2.5mbps

Comment: Hi @Idleguys,  set the DIU in copy active settings like the answer said.

Answer (score 1):

To increase DIU for a copy activity just click on the activity, and under the Settings tab you can find the Data Integration Unit selector.

[image: Increase DIU]

Comment: Apologies I was not clear in my post earlier, I know how to increase the DIU from Copy settings. When I changed to 16 and ran the pipeline with above configuration. During run time the DIU does not go beyond 4. Expectation is that copy activity should use 16 units but it is not. Isn't that so? Please advise Thanks!

Comment: @Idleguys Got it.

Comment: Then its probably an issue with the throughput of your data source, not Data Factory.

Comment: Thanks @MartinEstebanZurita for your response, my thro put is ~2.7mbps do you think this is low? if so, how can I increase this?

Comment: Slow or fast depends on your scenario, for most batch processes its fine. If DIU dont go higher than 4 because it is because it doesnt need to go higher to handle that

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  My source is Azure Blob (csv files), Staging is also Azure Blob and final destination is Snowflake with Azure.   All in the same region/zone.

I have set DIU for 20 and Parallel to 4.   But only has DIU as 4 utilized and Parallel to 1.

Comment: This would be better as an upvote and a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31154089)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont have enough reputations to write a comment so posting it as an answer if this helps.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793642/diu-not-going-beyond-4) thread. This is similar to yours with data size of 3GB. So I assume when your data size increase your DIU will also change.

Alternatively, you can increase the Degree of copy Parallelism (DoCP). I tried in my case for a 1.5GB dataset with source as ADLS and sink as Azure table. With default DoCP *i.e. 4* the copy activity takes 10 minutes with throughput starting from 8Mbps and ends at 1.3Mbps. Where with DoCP as 16, the throughput ends with 2Mbps and it takes ~4 minutes to complete the copy activity. Both runs with a DIU of 4 units.